# Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Something is wrong. I stopped MaridaDB, moved `/var/lib/mysql` to a different place, then replaced the old mysql with a softlink

```
cd /var/lib
ln -s /data/mysql .
```

Then I added

```
chown -R mysql:mysql mysql
```

and then I went to `/data` and did the same (Note: this relocation works fine in regular mysql). But in MariaDB

> ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file
>   '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
>   [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't create file' when trying to use aria
>   control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria'
>   init function returned error. [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a
>   STORAGE ENGINE failed.

So what can I do to fix this? I tried setting

```
chmod 777 /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control
```

but to no avail.

Comment: This will be helpful https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160277

Comment: Revert any config changes you've made to the log file size and start MySQL again.
1) In your running MySQL: SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown=0;
Stop MySQL
2) Make the configuration change to the log file size.
3) Delete both log files.
4) Start MySQL. It will complain about the lack of log files, but it'll create them and all will be well.

Comment: Neither of the answers provided have much to do with the issue. My server keeps refusing to load.

Comment: [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=1602497
131122 17:56:55 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
131122 17:56:55 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
131122 17:56:55 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.6 started; log sequence number 1602572
131122 17:56:55 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
131122 17:56:55 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't create file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'

Answer (score 8):

In my case the problem was that while directory mysql and files within were owned by user mysql, the path has a directory that lacked x bit for the users that are not in the correct group. In other words, user could not move to the target directory because one of the directories in the path did not allow it.

Comment: Hello @Zds, I know that this is an old answer, but could you specify step by step solution to the problem? I'm still new to Linux and it seems this was the only answer related to my question (I came from Google Search). *At least reference would be nice*. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't have time to get very comprehensive, thus posting only a comment for now. This wiki page might help you forward: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes

Essentially, if you have a file /var/foo/bar, if directories /var and /var/foo don't have permission x (execute), you can't reach the file foo, even if that file itself has permissions that allow you to read it.

Comment: Hi @Zds, I actually solved my problem via re-installing MariaDB. And it works perfectly! And thanks for replying I will still take a look at the files since I'm still a newbie on Linux anyway.

Comment: Just expanding on @Zds comment which fixed my problem... `cd` to whatever directory you are having trouble with.  `ls -las` and for `.` directory at top see if permission string ends with `x` which would be execute for other.  If not, then `chmod o+x .`   Next `cd ..` and repeat.  Do this until you've checked all directories up to root.

Comment: To add `o+x` where needed you can inspect the full tree with `namei -l \`realpath .\``

Answer (score 0):

In My case this happened after a change which required OS restart, turned out that SELINUX was in ENFORCE mode and was not allowing MySQL to access the files, used below command to resolve:

sudo getenforce

sudo setenforce 0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).